# Sum of IID normal variables with index following Poisson distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, poisson-distribution, sum

$X_1, X_2,\ldots$ are a sequence of independent normal random variables with mean 1 and variance 1.
Calculate the variance of $X_1+X_2+X_3+\ldots+X_{N+1}$ where $N$ follows Poisson distribution with mean 2.

I know that variance of sum of independent random variables is the sum of variances, applying that I get the answer to be $N+1$, but that does not make sense since $N+1$ is a random variable itself.

Comment: By conditioning on $N$ you get rid of the problem that $N$ is random.  For instance, one part of the variance calculation is $$E[(X_1+\cdots+X_{N+1})^2]=E[E[(X_1+\cdots+X_{N+1})^2 \mid N]].$$This formula invites you to compute the expectation in two steps: in the first you may pretend $N$ is a (known) natural number. You will obtain a value that depends on $N.$ In the second step you compute the expectation of that value (given that $N$ has a Poisson$(2)$ distribution). This reasoning is general, leading to the [Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

Comment: More generally, the MGF can be computed this way and possibly [identify the distribution of the sum with a random number of sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation) following Wald's equation. And applies for instance to [branching processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process).